# How to convert String variable to int in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, int, type-conversion, numeric

What is the correct way to convert value of String variable to int/numeric variable? Why is `bcInt` still string and why does `isNaN` return `true`?

```
bc=localStorage.getItem('bc');
var bcInt=parseInt(bc,10);
var bcInt2=1;
console.log("bc------------>" +bc +" isNaN:" +isNaN(bc)); //isNaN returns true
console.log("bcInt------------>" +bcInt +" isNaN:" +isNaN(bcInt)); //isNaN returns true

bcInt2// isNaN returns false
```

Comment: If `parseInt()` returns a `NaN`, then your string doesn't actually contain a numeric representation of a value.  If you had told us what the value of "bc" is, then perhaps somebody could help, but you failed to do that. That value is of course the key to the whole problem.

Comment: What is the value contained in the local storage item `bc`? If it is not a number (empty, got alpha characters etc...), that's what I would expect to see.

Comment: 08-20 18:41:02.880: bc------------>"1" isNaN:true

Comment: If there are double-quote characters around the `1` then it's not going to work.

Comment: Pointy got a point. I used stringify function in another place and then there was a double-quote and that was the reason! Thanks for helping me everybody.

Answer (score 9):

`parseInt` returns a number only if you pass it a number as first character.

Examples:

```
parseInt( 'a', 10 ); // NaN
parseInt( 'a10', 10 ); // NaN
parseInt( '10a', 10 ); // 10
parseInt( '', 10 ); // NaN
parseInt( '10', 10 ); // 10
```

Also, you may take a look at the `+` operator if you want to get strings that are only numbers.

```
+'a'; // NaN
+'a10'; // NaN
+'10a'; // NaN
+''; // 0, that's tricky
+'10'; // 10
```

Edit: According to your comment, I've tested `parseInt`:

```
parseInt( '08-20 19:41:02.880', 10 ); // 8
```

You're doing something else wrong. `parseInt` returns everything till it's not a number. If the first isn't a number (or it doesn't find any number), it returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAWhA.jpg)

let no = "25";

typeof no
'string'

let no2 = parseInt(no);
no2
25

typeof no2
'number'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34535334)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I used `localStorage.setItem('bc',JSON.stringify(bc))` and it added double quote to `bc` because it was in that case already a string and that's why `parseInt` wasn't working. Value was `""1""`.

Comment: i have the same problem as this. still dont have a solution