# How can I convert my string to a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert String variable to int in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040769/how-to-convert-string-variable-to-int-in-javascript)

I have the following:

```
var dataElapsed = $("#stats-list").attr("data-elapsed");
```

This creates a string called dataElapsed but I expect a number. How can I convert this?

Is there some way to convert with JQuery? or do I have to use some Javascript way?

Comment: `var dataElapsed = $("#stats-list").attr("data-elapsed")*1;`

Comment: @Geek - I tried adding a "+" before the $ is this also valid as it seems to work.

Comment: @SamanthaJ yes I believe it would be valid - but if the data is a negative number that would reverse the sign-ness

Comment: @Geek - your suggestion gives me a typescript error :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this(assuming the data attributes have valid numeric values):

```
var dataElapsed = parseFloat($("#stats-list").attr("data-elapsed")); //for decimal.
```

or

```
var dataElapsed = parseInt($("#stats-list").attr("data-elapsed"), 10); //for integer.
```

Comment: I just tried to add a "+"before the $ and it worked. Is this an okay way to do this. It seems simpler.

Comment: I would argue that _parseInt_ is much better (not sure why you don't think it's simple enough).  This way your code is self documenting: it is obvious what is happening.  If you use a trick like inserting a plus sign, it's far less obvious (and kinda hacky).  Trying to get cute just to save a few keystrokes often causes confusion and bugs.

Comment: @Chandu - I decided to agree with you :-)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) method to get values from data attributes

```
var dataElapsed = $("#stats-list").data("elapsed");
```

Comment: Hi Musa. I think this is not the answer to the question. My question was how can I make sure a number is returned.

Comment: @SamanthaJ It is returned as a number `Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)`

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now. However are .data attributes not stored differently with JQuery. For example if I have code setting .data then can I see it in the browser with firebug?